# Show Calendar List as Home Page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a calender list on my site and I'd like it to be the home page. How do I update it to make it my home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the site in SharePoint Designer. Click on All files. Then click on Lists Folder. Locate the Calendar List. Click on it. Now find the page and right click on it. Set as home page.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Look and Feel -> Welcome Page

Set this to your page showing the calendar list.

Comment: I tried that but the option for the welcome page is not there.